# What is the architecture of a scikit-learn MLPRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I am using a `MLPRegressor`, and want to make sure I understand the architecture being fit.

Here is the model:

```py
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_scaled[1:6000], y[1:6000], train_size=0.5, test_size=0.25)

mlp = neural_network.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 20), activation="relu",
                 solver='adam', alpha=0.0001,
                 batch_size='auto', learning_rate="constant",
                 learning_rate_init=0.001,
                 max_iter=1000,tol=1e-4)

mlp.fit(x_train, y_train)
r = mlp.score(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = mlp.predict(x_test)
```

I want to check my understanding of the architecture here. Are there:

- 6 units in the input layer if I am using 6 inputs in `x`?
- 2 hidden layers of 1000 and 20 units respectively?
- an output layer with 1 unit?

Answer (score 1):

Almost (unless the 1000 units was a typo):

- 6 inputs in the input layer if the shape of `X` is `(_, 6)`
- 2 hidden layers with size **100** and 20, respectively
- 1 unit in the output layer since this is a regression task

More generally: these are properties that can be inspected using attributes of the `neural_network.MLPRegressor` object. For example:

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=6)

nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(100, 20), activation="relu",
                 solver='adam', alpha=0.0001,
                 batch_size='auto', learning_rate="constant",
                 learning_rate_init=0.001,
                 max_iter=1000,tol=1e-4)

nn.fit(X, y)

print(f"Number of inputs:  {nn.n_features_in_}")
print(f"Number of outputs: {nn.n_outputs_}")
print(f"Number of layers:  {nn.n_layers_}")
print(f"Layer sizes: {[l.shape for l in nn.coefs_]}")
```

Which shows us the number of inputs, outputs, layers, and sizes for coefficients in the hidden layers:

```
Number of inputs:  6
Number of outputs: 1
Number of layers:  4
Layer sizes: [(6, 100), (100, 20), (20, 1)]
```